# Можно ли группировать теги в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

подскажите пожалуйста, хочется добавить теги стран, авторов, и тем, можно их как то разделить что бы вывести в разные места. Теги авторов, теги тем, теги стран

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из коробки нельзя разделить метки. Более правильнее с вашей стороны зарегистировать 3 другие таксономии теги стран, теги тем и теги авторов.

https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_taxonomy

Параметр `hierarchical` делает таксономию по типу меток(false) или категорий(true).

```
'hierarchica' => false
```

Comment: Всё так, только в данном случае правильнее не "из коробки нельзя разделить метки", а "по-умолчанию зарегистрированы только метки". В коробке есть возможность можно создавать кастомную таксономию.